# A term or word used when finding something great

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word or term that is used when you find something great or of value. I'm looking particularly for when people find a great sale at a store or find an item for a bargain.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Can you write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a noun form of [steal (#14)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/steal):

> something acquired at a cost far below its real value; bargain: This
>   dress is a steal at $40.

[Edit: This answers the specific part of your question "I'm looking particularly for when people find a great sale at a store or find an item for a bargain."]

Answer (score 1):

eureka |yo͝oˈrēkə, yə-|
exclam.
a cry of joy or satisfaction when one finds or discovers something.
ORIGIN early 17th cent.: from Greek heurēka ‘I have found it’ (from heuriskein ‘find’), said to have been uttered by Archimedes when he hit upon a method of determining the purity of gold. The noun dates from the early 20th cent.
Also : A steal 
noun [ in sing. ]
1 informal a bargain: for $5 it was a steal.

Comment: Please add the name of the source of this definition, with a link if it is online.